# Python SQLite IN operator with a variable value

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-in

In Python SQLite, how do I make `(1, 2)` a variable, like in:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM basicinfo WHERE id IN (1, 2)')
```

Doing the following doesn't work:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM basicinfo WHERE id IN ?', (1, 2))
```

It gives the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 `?` placeholder in your sql statement but you want to pass a list of values and this is syntactically wrong.
You could use:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM basicinfo WHERE id IN ?", ("(1, 2)",))
```

but this would lead to this sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM basicinfo WHERE id IN '(1, 2)'
```

which is not what you want because the `?` placeholder would be replaced by the string literal `'(1, 2)'` and not a list of values.

In this case you can use the operator `LIKE`:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM basicinfo WHERE ',' || ? || ',' LIKE '%,' || id || ',%' ", ("1,2",))
```

You will have to remove parentheses and spaces from the comma separated list of values.

Comment: Hmm tricky way of using `LIKE`. I'm guessing if there is no more direct way then it might be better to just format the query myself in Python.

Comment: SQLite does not provide string functions which you could use to parse a comma separated list (for example MySql has find_in_set()), so like is the only option if you don't want to create the sql statement with concatenations in a loop. And yes it would work with strings. It would create a statement like this: `like ',a,b,c,' like '%,b,%'`